# Inserting a new column in a dynamically allocated 2D Matrix

Tags: c++, memory-management

I want to add a new column in an 2D dynamically allocated matrix. I've managed to make an algorithm to add a new row, but I can't figure out how to do it for a column.

I've found something written in C, but i can't figure out how to "translate" it in C++, if any of you can help or explain how can I do it, I will be very grateful.

```
    void AddColumn(int **matrix, int nrR,int &nrc,int *v,int position)
{

/* mat = (int**)realloc(mat, (nrc + 1) * sizeof(int*));
    nrc++; What I found written in C*/
// nrc= number of columns
//mat=matrix
mat[nrc-1]=new int[nrc];// What I think it will be good
nrc++;
for(int index1=0;index1<nrR;index1++
{
  for(int index2=nrc-1;index2>position;index2--)
  {
    matrix[index1][index2]=matrix[index1][index2-1];
  }
}

for(int index3=position;index3<nrr;index3++) // REPLACE THE ELEMENTS WITH
 { //THE NEW COLUMN
   matrix[index3][position]=v[index3];
 }

}

}
```

Also, this is for learning purposes, that's why I didn't use `std::vector` .

Answer (score 1):

First, well-formatted C compiles into C++ just fine, so if your C code isn't particularly dirty, you can use it the way it is.

But let's see what I would do...

```
class TwoDArray {
private:
    int ** data;
    int width;
    int height;

public:
    TwoDArray(): data(nullptr), width(0), height(0) { }
    ~TwoDArray() { if (data != nullptr) {
       ...
    }}

    //
    // use 0 for front of matrix.
    //
    void addColumn(int beforeLocation) {
        int newWidth = width + 1;
        for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row) {
            int * oldRow = data[row];
            int * newRow = new int[newWidth];
            // Copy everything before the insert location
            for (int col = 0; col < beforeLocation; ++col) {
                newRow[col] = oldRow[col];
            }
            newRow[beforeLocation] = 0;
            // Copy from the insert location forward
            for (int col = beforeLocation; col < width; ++col) {
                newRow[col + 1] = oldRow[col];
            }
            // Point data to use the new array of data and
            // release the memory from the old one.
            data[row] = newRow;
            delete [] oldRow;
        }
    }
};
```

I haven't tried compiling this. But now you would have a class that knows what a 2-D matrix of ints is. You would need more methods for accessing, freeing data, etc.

So... something like this.

Comment: Side note: Make sure you take the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (and Five if you got 'em) into account or one accidental copy will result in a LOT of painful debugging.

Answer (score 1):

simple example function:

```
void AddColumn(int ** matrix, int numRows, int numCols)
{
    /*
        matrix[row][column]

        example: rows = 4 cols = 5

        ---------------------------------
        |   12  51  16  90  3   matrix[0][0-4]
        |   34  1   4   0   7   matrix[1][0-4]
        |   0   0   0   0   22  matrix[2][0-4]
        |   0   0   0   0   88  matrix[3][0-4]

        adding a column requires: reallocating every row array,
        copying the values over, and deleting the old arrays
    */

    int i = 0, j = 0; //index values
    int *temp; // will hold a temporary copy of the old int array
    for (;i < numRows; i++)
    {
        // reallocating
        temp = matrix[i];
        matrix[i] = new int[numCols + 1];

        //copying old values
        for (j = 0;j < numCols;j++)
            matrix[i][j] = temp[j];

        // ensuring the new values are initialized
        // to a default value
        matrix[i][numCols] = 0;

        //deleting the old array
        delete[] temp;
    }//end for

    /*
    matrix should now be:
    ---------------------------------
    |   12  51  16  90  3   0   matrix[0][0-5]
    |   34  1   4   0   7   0   matrix[1][0-5]
    |   0   0   0   0   22  0   matrix[2][0-5]
    |   0   0   0   0   88  0   matrix[3][0-5]

*/
}//endfunc
```